# testing nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

before I ask the question I want to give a little background on the models. I have a user_conversation model(through table) which accepts attributes from conversations and messages models. The create action and before action are given below.

```
 before_action :logged_in_user
 before_action :validate_conversation, only: :create

    def create
         redirect_to home_path unless current_user
         @conversation = UserConversation.new conversation_params
         @conversation.user = current_user
         @conversation.conversation.messages.first.user = current_user
         @conversation.save!
         activate_unread
         redirect_to user_conversation_path(current_user,@conversation)
        end

Private

def validate_conversation
        @user = User.find params[:user_id]
        if params[:user_conversation][:conversation_attributes]["subject"].blank? 
            redirect_to new_user_conversation_path(@user)
            flash[:danger] = "Subject cannot be blank"
        else params[:user_conversation][:conversation_attributes][:messages_attributes]["0"]["body"].blank?
            redirect_to new_user_conversation_path(@user)
            flash[:danger] = "Message cannot be blank"
        end
    end

 def conversation_params
     params.require(:user_conversation).permit(:recipient_id, conversation_attributes: [:subject, messages_attributes: [:body]])
 end
```

I was trying to write an integration tests for the post request of user_conversation. The test is given below.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ConversationCreateTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup 
    @user = users(:user_a)
    @conversation = conversations(:convo_one)
  end

  test "invalid creation of a user conversation no subject" do 
    log_in_as(@user)
    get new_user_conversation_path(@user)
    post user_conversations_path(@user), user_conversation: {:recipient_id => @user.id, :conversation_attributes => {:subject => "this is a subject", 
                                                              :message_attributes => {"0" => {:body => "sending a message"}}}}
  end
```

I get the following error message when I run the command.

```
1) Error:
ConversationCreateTest#test_invalid_creation_of_a_user_conversation_no_subject:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/user_conversations_controller.rb:63:in `validate_conversation'
    test/integration/conversation_create_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:ConversationCreateTest>'

191 runs, 398 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

I have been trying to debug the problem for about 2 hours. I have checked the test log files and it says internal server error 500. I have tried commenting certain lines of codes to narrow down the problem but not really sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if `params[:user_conversation]` is blank, then the code will explode when you try to run `params[:user_conversation][:conversation_attributes]`... you have to test every part of that line... or better yet... you shouldn't be doing validations in the controller - that's what models are for.

Comment: @TarynEast, I tested for the validations in the models, they work perfectly fine. I just want to test the post request. I think the error is saying that one of those params is nil.

Comment: "just want to test the post request" refers to something inside your head that you haven't explained out loud to us yet :) if the validations work in the models, then why are you writing one in the controller? It literally should not be there... and the most likely reason why your code is failing is because the `params[:user_conversation]` is blank at some point.... why don't you remove that before_action from your  controller entirely - and move that logic into the models instead, and see what happens.

Comment: Otherwise tell us what you're trying to do and we'll figure out the Rails Best practice way of doing it (which is definitely not this)

Comment: Agreed---test_invalid_creation_of_a_user_conversation_no_subject has absolutely nothing to do with the controller.  Write two tests for you model...one that passes with valid params and one that fails when subject is nil.  Also, rename your spec---I cant tell if test_invalid_creation is supposed to be valid or invalid without a subject.  Try 'conversation should be invalid without subject'.

Answer (score 0):

In rails, validations are made with the `ActiveModel::Validators`.

So you can simply validate your model like this:

User:

```
class User
  has_many :conversations, through: "user_conversations"
end
```

Conversation:

```
class Conversation
  has_many :users, through: "user_conversations"

  validates_presence_of :subject, :messages
end
```

[See more here about validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

So if you then need to validate your model you can call:

```
conversation = Conversation.create(subject: nil)
conversation.errors.full_messages # => ["Subject can't be blank"]
```

I think you'll need to rewrite a bunch of things in your app, and if you took the code above you can simply test this thing within a model (unit) test.

Which, by the way, is no longer needed because you don't want to test the rails provided validators. You probably just want to test your own validators.